# Nonstandard view of an external SVG document embedded in HTML via a fragment identifier or view specification: How to manipulate the viewBox?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom

*NOTE: This question has been substantially rewritten, which on the one hand makes everything much more concise, but on the other hand might have robbed some of the comments of their context. I hope the conversation is still understandable.*

I am embedding SVG images as `<object>s`in an HTML page, and make them zoomable and pannable with JavaScript, where all the event handlers are called on the `rootElement`of each object's `contentDocument`, i.e. the `<svg>`, and manipulate its `viewBox.baseVal` property.

A minimal working example (reduced to the panning functionality) follows. We have an SVG file called `circle_and_rectangle.svg`:

```html
<svg style="background: white" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="299" height="299" style="fill:grey"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="75" style="fill:red"/>
</svg>
```

and an HTML file that imports this SVG file in an `<object>` element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>External SVG embedding</title>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    svgRoot = document.getElementById('foo').contentDocument.rootElement
    svgRoot.addEventListener('mousedown', activatePanning,   false);
    svgRoot.addEventListener('mouseup',   deactivatePanning, false);
  }
 
  function activatePanning (event) {
    this.addEventListener('mousemove', panOnMouseMove, false)
  }

  function panOnMouseMove (event) {
    baseVal = this.viewBox.baseVal
    baseVal.x -= (event.movementX / this.clientWidth)  * baseVal.width
    baseVal.y -= (event.movementY / this.clientHeight) * baseVal.height
  }

  function deactivatePanning (event) {
    this.removeEventListener('mousemove', panOnMouseMove, false)
  }
</script>

<object id="foo" style="width:400px;height:300px;border: 1px solid green"
    type="image/svg+xml" data="circle_and_rectangle.svg">
</object>
```

As intended, this shows a red circle against a grey square (inside a slightly wider green frame) which can be dragged back and forth with the mouse.

*NOTE: This only works when the files are accessed via a server, whether on the Web or on the local computer. (See comments for details. As soon as I've found one that lets me sign up without Facebook & the like, I'll put them on a suitable code-sharing website.)*

I've now found it would be very useful if I could embed just partial views of the SVG images, which SVG makes possible by either of the following two methods, (I've left out required attributes for the sake of brevity):

```html
<object ... data="circle_and_rectangle.svg#svgView(viewBox(75,75,150,150))"></object>

<!-- or, the SVG contains: -->
<view id="closeup" viewBox="75 75 150 150" />
<!-- and the HTML, instead of the above: -->
<object ... data="circle_and_rectangle.svg#closeup"></object>
```

As expected, either results in a close-up (or zoomed-in) view of the red circle. However, **the panning no longer works**; the image is just fixed. On inspection:

- the viewBox values as accessed as described above (the `contentDocument.rootElement.viewBox.baseVal` property of the `<object>`) are the *standard* ones of said `<svg>` root element (i.e. the `0 0 300 300` in its `viewBox` attribute), *not* those of the viewBox actually *used* by the browser and specified directly in the URI resp. in the referenced `<view>`element.
- these values do get manipulated by the handlers as before, but that no longer has any visible effect

The described behaviour is identical in Chrome and Firefox (on Linux), regardless of whether a view specification (`#svgView(...)`) or a fragment identifier (`#closeup`) with a corresponding `<view id="closeup">` element in the SVG is used.

I've poked around the DOM of the `contentElement` and its `rootElement` and searched JavaScript references and the MDN and the Web for the better part of the afternoon, but nothing tangible has materialised on the following two questions:

- how can I access the viewBox values that are actually *used* in the above scenario (since the standard viewBox apparently isn't)?
- what exactly causes the nonfunctioning of the handlers? Since they *do* still manipulate the viewBox values of the `<svg>` element: is it indeed simply that they now operate on the wrong viewBox?
- more generally, is there *any* reliable way to pan and zoom when the SVG is loaded in such a nonstandard view?

Comment: You can't access those values as there's no API to allow you to do that. If you want to ask about the handlers, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the swift answer! I'll be happy to provide a trimmed-down example, though I suspect that due to the nature of the problem I would have to supply it as two files, and I think that cannot be tested directly here. Is that a problem?

Comment: @fsavigny if the code is such that one would copy-poste it and it would work locally on one's computer, then it is perfect. Focus on making the code reproducible (showing your problem) and ideally minimal (trimming all unnecessary stuff). Often you find (or at least closely bound) the problem while creating the Minimum Reproducible Example.

Comment: @RobertLongson what happened to [SVGSVGElement.currentView](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__currentView) isn't it supposed to be exactly that? The [MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement#Browser_compatibility) states that Firefox supports it (though it doesn't seem to be there on mine, only `useCurrentView` is defined...)

Comment: @Kaiido Firefox has never supported currentView. It's been removed from SVG 2.  useCurrentView has been removed too but thus far we've not removed it from Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok. So MDN compatibility table should get updated? Found [that](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/747), maybe OP could make their point for an use-case not to remove it, or do you think it's too late now. (Sounds anyway weird to me that this has been removed but not the `<view>` and fragment identitfier `#svgView`). I understand your point there that they were ill defined, but that doesn't mean they're not needed).

Comment: @kaiido Feel free to update MDN. I'd be in favour of creating a better API to replace currentView, but you'd need Chrome or Safari to sign up to doing that.

Comment: @RobertLongson Safari does support `SVGSVGElement.currentView`.

Comment: Sorry for taking so much time. The handlers are ALL triggered (stupid error on my part), they just have no visible effect. I've corrected that. -- I have succeeded in putting together a minimal example, but it only works locally if one runs a local webserver to serve the two files (e.g. `webfsd -r . -e 1`)  because otherwise, `contentDocument` returns `null` instead of the SVG document. Will that also do?

Comment: @Kalido My use case is that I would like to load an SVG in a nonstandard initial view and then be able to pan and zoom it (and also reset to that initial view), If that can be achieved _without_ accessing these nonstandard viewBox coordinates (or perhaps even without manipulating the viewBox at all), that would be fine as well. (Even though that would appear awkward to me -- the viewBox concept is very versatile once you've got your head round it.)

Comment: Explanation of the above: I use `contentDocument.rootElement` to get the `<svg>` root element to register the handlers on it. It seems that when browsers access the HTML document as a file, they do load the SVG too, but it somehow does not seem to be accessible via the DOM methods. (Or is there another way??)

Comment: Yes I understand your use case, but in the absence of an API you'd have to do horrible things like parsing the the `location.hash` and either edit it or find the linked `<view>` and edit its `viewBox` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a non default view (either `<view>` or `#svgView()`), its parameters will be used instead of the ones of the root element.

So if you set a `viewBox` parameter through this *view*, the root element's `viewBox` will get discarded, and editing it won't change anything.

There used to be an [SVGSVGElement.currentView](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__currentView) property being defined in SVG1.1, but it got dropped in SVG2 and among popular modern browsers, only Safari did implement it.

Since there is no clean API to deal with it, you will need to do something a bit dirty by checking the `location.hash` if it's pointing to such a *view* and edit it or the element it points to.

However if I understand your case correctly, you have full control over the svg and you know for sure you'll be using such a view, so the easiest is probably to use a `<view>` element and then to edit its `viewBox` attribute, **except that Chrome is buggy and doesn't update the view when this happens...**

Here is a live snippet where the edition is made from inside the svg document itself since StackSnippets iframes don't allow accessing the inner doc **which only works in Firefox**.

```js
const svg_content = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" >
  <view id="my_view" viewBox="0 0 400 400" />
  <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"/>
  <script>
    onmousemove = (evt) => {
      const view = document.getElementById("my_view");
      const viewBox = view.viewBox.baseVal;
      viewBox.x = evt.clientX * -1;
      viewBox.y = evt.clientY * -1;
    };
  <\/script>
</svg>`;
const blob = new Blob([svg_content], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const object = document.getElementById("obj");
object.data = url + "#my_view";
```

```css
object {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<object id="obj"></object>
```

And even changing the `<object>`'s `data` with an updated `#svgView()` won't work in that browser, apparently crashing the parser...

So I'm sorry to be the one to tell you, but there doesn't seem to be any cross-browser way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Kalido! It seems to me that yes, you're the one to tell me, and - barring anything unexpected that still shows up - this is an entirely comprehensive answer. -- As my aim is to make the information in the SVGs broadly accessible, the workarounds you have tried out and suggested regrettably won't do. (But thanks very much for trying out!) So I'll have to try something else entirely, and, for the future, try to lobby the standard makers on this one, because this seems to be an inconsistency which I find difficult to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much again! (I was still wondering a bit if some White Knight would still come along and shout, "Wait! There actually IS an API that nobody has ever heard of!", but I'll renege on that hope now.) Many thanks also @Robert Longson for saving me a lot of time with his supersonic answer - time that might have been stimulating but frustrating and wasted. As said, I'll look into what the standard makers are planning and contribute my 5 cents there, as I find this state of affairs very wondrous.